# Clustering items from matrix

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have a dictionary with this format

```
items = {"0":'lorem ipsum', "1":'blah blah', "2":'blah", "3":'lorem',.....}
```

Let's say that `len(items) = 70`

I have a 70x70 matrix with values for each pair of the dictionary. For instance, the `matrix[4][20]` representing the value between item 4 and 20 from the dictionary.

I want to cluster the dictionary items and put in the same group all items with a value more than a certain threshold. I don't know if my way is the best way. Maybe there is a library that can do the same thing much quicker than mine. Since my matrix could be 10000x10000.

```
size = range(0,len(items))
t = 1
mydict = {}
for i in size:
    mylist = items[i]
    size.remove(i)
    for j in size:
        if items[j] in lis:
            pass
        elif matrix[i][j] > 0.50:
            mylist.append(items[j])
            size.remove(j)
    mydict[t] = mylist
    t = t + 1
    mylist = []
```

And then I print all the groups with more than 5 items.

```
for i in mydict:
    if len(mydict[i]) > 5:
        print mydict[i]
        print ""
```

Do you see any error? Do know any library or a better algorithm to do this?

**UPDATED**
Here is a better example:

```
items = {"0": 'item 0', "1":'item 1', "2":'item 2', "3":'item 3', "4":'item 4', "5":'item 5'}

matrix = [[1.0 0.2 0.7 0.8 0.3 0.1],
          [0.2 1.0 0.2 0.3 0.6 0.2],
          [0.7 0.2 1.0 0.7 0.2 0.3],
          [0.8 0.3 0.7 1.0 0.2 0.4],
          [0.3 0.6 0.2 0.2 1.0 0.1],
          [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.1 1.0]]

**The results:**

[item 0, item 2, item 3]

[item 1, item 4]

[item 5]
```

The matrix is triangular and all the points in the diagonial are 1.

Comment: Could you please provide an illistrative example of incoming dictionary and desired result?

Comment: The incoming dictionary is the same as the example but the values are different. The key is an int from 0 to len(items). The output now is a list for each group. I will try to create an example with a dic,matrix and results

Comment: @J0HN I updated the question with an example.

Comment: Matrix is a product of some calculation on dictionary or just input/config parameter?

Comment: It is the text similarity of the values of the dictionary.

Comment: How do you get it? Is it calculated somehow?

Comment: TF-IDF with scikit-learn library. But I cannot see how those two have been related.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you are trying to do *hierarchical linkage clustering* with single-link, and then make a cut with the given threshold.

This is essentially equivalent to the minimum spanning tree (MST) problem, and that is also about as fast as you can get: `O(n^2)` where `n` is the number of items.

So I believe your algorithm is reasonable. Note that the SciPy implementation of hierarchical clustering only supports Ward linkage, not single-linkage, and probably has `O(n^3)` complexity.

If you want to make things quicker, try to not build the matrix the first place. But keep a set of clusters, and join these appropriately by adding one element at a time. Essentially, for each new item, find all items that are above your threshold. Then you can get three cases: 1. there is no other cluster nearby. Then start a new cluster with the current item. 2. there is exactly one cluster, add the current item to this cluster. 3. there is more than one cluster. Merge all of these, and then add the current item.

```
class cluster:
    def __init__(self, first):
        self.members = [first]

mydict = {}
for i in range(0,len(items)):
    nearby = set()
    for j in range(0, i):
        if matrix[i][j] > 0.5: nearby.add(mydict[j])
    if len(nearby) == 0:
        mydict[i] = cluster(i)
    else:
        mydict[i] = nearby.pop()
        mydict[i].members.append(i)
        for other in nearby: # merge other clusters
            mydict[i].members.extend(other.members)
            for k in other.members: mydict[k] = mydict[i]
```

Note that I am deliberately keeping track only of integers. Saving memory is key to handling large data sets, and integers are just the most efficient entity you have.

Comment: I like your idea. I have already implement hierachical clustering with scipy but it is slower than my way. I will try your way this afternoon and I will wait if anyone else suggest anything, otherwise, I will choose your answer as the best :)